# Batch Input Keras Shared Parameters

Tags: python, keras

I am building network to rank a set of N inputs. Ideally they should all be input at the same time and share parameters. Their target vector should be an N-hot vector to match the inputs.

This means my input should be (Batch_size, N, sequence_length, feature_length)

But keras will throw an error for any input larger than 3 dimensions as shown here:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_2: expected
>   ndim=3, found ndim=4

My current keras set up is:

```
x = Input(shape=(72,300))
aux_input = Input(shape=(72, 4))
probs = Input(shape=(1,))
#dim_red_1 = Dense(100)(x)
dim_red_2 = Dense(20, activation='tanh')(x)
cat = concatenate([dim_red_2, aux_input])
encoded = LSTM(64)(cat)
cat2 = concatenate([encoded, probs])
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(cat2)

lstm_model = Model(inputs=[x, aux_input, probs], outputs=output)
lstm_model.compile(optimizer='ADAM', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Is there a way to achieve this with Keras?

Answer (score 0):

Although your code seems to be fine, make sure to import the right packages:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.keras import Input
from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Concatenate

a = np.zeros(shape=[1000, 72, 300])
b = np.zeros(shape=[1000, 72, 4])
c = np.zeros(shape=[1000, 1])
d = np.zeros(shape=[1000, 1])

x = Input(shape=(72, 300))
aux_input = Input(shape=(72, 4))
probs = Input(shape=(1,))
dim_red_2 = Dense(20, activation='tanh')(x)
cat = Concatenate()([dim_red_2, aux_input])
encoded = LSTM(64)(cat)
cat2 = Concatenate()([encoded, probs])
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(cat2)

lstm_model = Model(inputs=[x, aux_input, probs], outputs=output)
lstm_model.compile(optimizer='ADAM', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
lstm_model.summary()
lstm_model.fit([a, b, c], d, batch_size=256)
```

output:

```
256/1000 [======>.......................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 1.0000
 512/1000 [==============>...............] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.6910 - acc: 1.0000
 768/1000 [======================>.......] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6885 - acc: 1.0000
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6859 - acc: 1.00
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but your input is rank 3 I am trying to input a rank 4 of shape (Batch_size, Group_size, sequence_length, feature_length). Do you know if this is possible?